# Cross-browser issue: How do I debug my site's behavior on safari with window PC?

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser

Live page: [tt.fbcwinterretreat.org](http://tt.fbcwinterretreat.org)

The page and its script work well with chrome, IE and firefox. But on iPhone/iPads, not only the layout messed up, but also the image carousel doesn't work. I don't have a mac so I havn't tested it on Mac, but I'm quite sure it won't work on Mac either.  To find the problem, I need something like chrome's dev tools to debug it, the question is, how do I do it with a window PC?

I have tried safari for windows, it turns out Safari has stopped support for window since 2012. And the latest version(5.1.7) is totally unreliable. So how do you guys make sure your sites/codes work on Safari if you have only window PC? I believe this must be a very general question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to buy a (second-hand) Mac. Apple does not allow installation of OS X on any machine than a Mac so running a virtual machine is not an option. Alternatively you could use one of the online browser compatibility tools such as
http://crossbrowsertesting.com/ although they are relatively pricey, but in return they provide a comprehensive list of browsers and browser versions.

Comment: A virtual machine [**is an option**](http://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox), although it's a pain to get it to work (and not legal).